# How can I separate code in main.ts in Vue 3?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm new to Typescript and vue and I'm curious how I could pull out this code in my main.ts file. I'm just worried it's going to get really ugly eventually.

```
const app = createApp(App);

/* import the fontawesome core */
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
/* import font awesome icon component */
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
/* import specific icons */
import { faHammer, faTruckPickup, faSortDown } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
/* add icons to the library */
library.add(faHammer, faMagnifyingGlass, faSortDown)

app.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon);
```

I would like my main.ts file to look something like this (doesn't have to be exact if there is a better way to do this).

```
import {addFontAwesomeIcons} from './fontAwesomeLibrary'

const app = createApp(app);

addFontAwesomeIcons(app); //this will use the app object and call library.add() and app.component('font-awesome-icon',FontAwesomeIcon);
```

So that my main.ts doesn't get polluted the more icons I have to add.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**fontAwesomeLibraryPlugin.ts**

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import { faHammer, faTruckPickup, faSortDown } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
library.add(faHammer, faMagnifyingGlass, faSortDown)

export const falPlugin = {
  install(app) {
    app.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon);
  }
}
```

**main.ts**

```
import { falPlugin } from './fontAwesomeLibraryPlugin'
const app = createApp(App);

app.use(falPlugin);
app.mount('#app');
```

Documented [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/plugins.html#plugins).